# jquery validate plugin with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

Has anyone tried jquery validate plugin with bootstrap modal form on click of a button. I am executing the below code on click of button but its not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated. My code can also be looked at https://jsfiddle.net/dharmjit/unr17s9u/2/

```js
$('#addForm').validate({
      rules: {
        User_ID: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 10,
          messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.validator
              .format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"),
            maxlength: jQuery.validator
              .format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
          }
        },
        First_Name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 10,
          messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.validator
              .format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"),
            maxlength: jQuery.validator
              .format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
          },
          highlight: function(element) {
            $(element)
              .closest('.form-group')
              .removeClass('success')
              .addClass('error');
          },
          success: function(element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass(
                'valid').closest(
                '.form-group')
              .removeClass('error')
              .addClass('success');
          }
        });
```

Comment: My code can be looked at https://jsfiddle.net/dharmjit/unr17s9u/2/

Comment: The *entirety* of the *relevant* code should also be posted within your OP.    Do not rely on the jsFiddle to show the HTML.  Thanks.  In this case, the entire issue was caused by a mismatch between the HTML and jQuery... which additionally mismatches what's in the jsFiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dharmjit/unr17s9u/2/), it does not match the code in your OP:

**OP**:

- jQuery:  `User_ID` and `First_Name`
- HTML: not shown

**jsFiddle**:

- jQuery: `firstname` and `lastname`
- HTML: `username` and `password`

---

1. In the jsFiddle, your rules are declared on `firstname` and `lastname`, while your actual fields are named `username` and `password`.  The `name` attributes of the fields must exactly correspond to the names used within the `rules` object of `.validate()`.
2. Looking at the JavaScript console, I'm seeing a *".validate is not a function"* message.  Paying attention to jsFiddle's warning message, if you don't use a `https` URL when adding the external resource, it will not work.  I switched the jQuery Validate plugin to its [secure CDN link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js).
3. You do not need to include both CSS files for Bootstrap.  The minified version has the same CSS rules/properties as the un-minified version.  Remove one.

Otherwise, the code as you've posted it, is fully working as designed:  **https://jsfiddle.net/unr17s9u/4/**

Comment: Hi Sparky, Thanks for your comments. Actually i wrote a similar code in jsfiddle to my production code in which i made silly mistakes as you have pointed. I am marking this as right answer. Can we also make it work on click of button with type other than submit.